# Reverse link direction of singly linked list

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I have a linked list that is reverse linked, is there a way I can **change the direction of the links** in this program? I've tried using `self.head.set_next` starting at the first element, but type `None` doesn't have a method `set_next`, so I'm not sure how I would proceed.

```
class Node2(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next_node = new_next

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

class LinkedList2(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that would do the trick

```
# linked_list is the list you want to reverse
previous_node = None
current_node = linked_list.head

while current_node is not None:
    next_node = current_node.get_next()
    current_node.set_next(previous_node)
    previous_node, current_node = current_node, next_node

linked_list.head = previous_node
```

This will execute in linear time.

However, if you find you need to frequently reverse linked list, you may find [doubly linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) to be more adapted to your needs

Comment: Are there only two ways to create a forward linked list? 1) By reversing a backward linked list, or 2) Using a doubly linked list?  Or is there a way to create a forward linked list from the start?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "from the start". Like creating a linked list from an iterator?

Comment: @123 *is there a way to create a forward linked list from the start* Yes? You build a forward linked list....  the only difference between a "forward" list and a "reversed" list is how you mentally think about it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively as well:

```
prev_node = 
cur_node = linked_list.head

def reverse_ll(prev, cur):
    if not cur: return prev
    next_node = cur.get_next()
    cur.set_next(prev)
    return reverse_ll(cur, next_node)

reversed_head = reverse_ll(None, cur_node)
```